# Getting the value from an array in the model in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, activerecord, view

I have a relatively simple problem. I have a model named Item which I've added a status field. The status field will only have two options (Lost or Found). So I created the following array in my Item model:

```
STATUS = [ [1, "Lost"], [2, "Found"]]
```

In my form view I added the following code which works great:

```
<%= collection_select :item, :status, Item::STATUS, :first, :last, {:include_blank => 'Select status'}  %>
```

This stores the numeric id (1 or 2) of the status in the database. However, in my show view I can't figure out how to convert from the numeric id (again, 1 or 2) to the text equivalent of Lost or Found.

Any ideas on how to get this to work? Is there a better way to go about this?

Many thanks,
Tony

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a method in your Item model:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  #
  def status_str
    Item::STATUS.assoc(status).last
  end
end
```

And use it:

```
item.status_str # => "Lost" (if status == 1)
```

Or you can check out [enum_fu](http://github.com/ikspres/enum_fu) plugin:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  #
  acts_as_enum :status, ["Lost", "Found"]
end
```

and then `item.status` gives you string value:

```
item.status # => "Lost"
```

Comment: Perfect! I ended up going with your first suggestion as it isn't much work and I'd like to keep the code as simple as possible. THANK YOU!